# Java fx2 I want to resizing image before save this

Tags: javafx-2, javax.imageio, filechooser

I make a javafx application (javafx 2, jdk 7u72) in which the user can import (with file chooser) an image and this is stored in an external folder.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;


public class FXMLDocumentbilController implements Initializable {


    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();        
        fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(
        new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));

       fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
       new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Icons JPG, PNG, GIF", "*.jpg", "*.gif", "*.png") );
       File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

       Path sourceFile = Paths.get(file.toString());
       Path destinationFile = Paths.get("c:\\librafolder\\fotomath", file.getName());        

        try {         
            Files.copy(sourceFile, destinationFile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentbilController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

I want the image is automatically reduced to 25 or 30 kb or 250X250 and then stored in the folder.

Comment: This code is a piece of my javafx application. Every image file where user choose (and that may be 2Mb or 10 Mb) loaded on the application for displaying. That spend too much ram memory. For this reason must every image file to minimize in 25 or 30 kb before execute the line code: Files.copy(sourceFile, destinationFile);

Comment: I understand. But what have you tried, to actually reduce the image/file size, so far? Also, keep in mind that stackoverflow is not a code factory. :-)

Comment: Ok, I will try to solve this problem, but I have not experience with javafx 2. Then I post any solution I find for correction by stackoverflow users.

Answer (score 0):

I find a very good solution from this website
http://blog.codejava.net/nam/reduce-image-quality-without-resizing/

```
package bilpir;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
import javax.imageio.stream.FileImageOutputStream;


public class FXMLDocumentbilController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

        try {         
            //Files.copy(sourceFile, destinationFile);

     float quality = 0.2f;

        Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg");  

        ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter)iter.next();  

        ImageWriteParam iwp = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();  

        iwp.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);  

        iwp.setCompressionQuality(quality);  

        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();        
        fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(
        new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));

       fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
       new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Icons JPG, PNG, GIF", "*.jpg", "*.gif", "*.png") );
       File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);      


       Path sourceFile = Paths.get(file.toString());
       Path destinationFile = Paths.get("c:\\bilpir", file.getName()); 

       FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile.toString());  
       BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(inputStream); 

        File file2 = new File(destinationFile.toString());  
        FileImageOutputStream output = new FileImageOutputStream(file2);  
        writer.setOutput(output);

        IIOImage image = new IIOImage(originalImage, null, null);  
        writer.write(null, image, iwp);  
        writer.dispose(); 


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentbilController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```